# How to call function from an Array in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to call the function from an array .My code is

```
$params = array(
            'df' => $this->_data['df'],
            'fl' => implode(',', $this->_data['fl']),
            'wt' => $this->_data['wt'],
            'q' => $this->_data['select'],
            'sort' => '',
            'fq' => implode(' ', $fq),
            'indent' => 'true',
            'start' => $this->_data['range'][0],
            'rows' => $this->_data['range'][1],
            'defType' => $this->_data['defType'],
            'qf' => implode(' ', $qf),
        );
```

i want to call function-"WordSplit" from an array:

```
  'q' => WordSplit($this->_data['select']);
```

Is it possible to do this in PHP?
Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, provided that the function returns a value; notice that you're already using the [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function to define some of the array values. You will need to end the "q" definition with a comma rather than a semicolon (just like in your original array), because other definitions are to follow. Does something go wrong when you try it?

Comment: @Rizier123 I want to implement my own logic with a function and I want to return a value from the function and I want that Function to be declared in an Array. Is there any way?

Comment: Have you tried to do it?

Comment: @Rizier123 Hey it works. Thanks!!

Comment: So your code works? You just never actually tried it? That's funny.

Answer (score 1):

As has been said, "the answer is, 'yes.'"  `WordSplit()` is a function, therefore a call to that function is a valid expression.  It can be used to provide a value for an array-element.

Now, what *I* would do, instead, is to add a new statement after the existing one:

```
$params['q'] = WordSplit(params['q']);
```

Why?  Because the very-harried person who's reading our code, someday in the future, might not *notice* that element `'q'` is being handled differently!  Purely for the sake of readability *(and possible future maintainability),* I would choose to do this as a separate statement.  The `$params` array is first "assembled," in a construct where the action for every element in the array is more-or-less the same.  Then, element `'q'` is manipulated.  (And I would place all other such "manipulations" adjacent to this one.  *"Clarity... Clarity...")*